# Does TOP function not work the same way as LIMIT in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Data

```
+----+-----------+--------------+------------+--------+------------+
| id |   action  |  question_id |  answer_id |  q_num |  timestamp |
+----+-----------+--------------+------------+--------+------------+
|  5 |  "show"   |          285 |  null      |      1 |        123 |
|  5 |  "answer" |          285 |  124124    |      1 |        124 |
|  5 |  "show"   |          369 |  null      |      2 |        125 |
|  5 |  "skip"   |          369 |  null      |      2 |        126 |
+----+-----------+--------------+------------+--------+------------+
```

MYSQL

```
select question_id as survey_log
from
(
    SELECT sum(CASE WHEN action='answer' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num,
    question_id,
    count(distinct id) as den
    from
    survey_log
    group by question_id
) b
order by (num/den) desc
limit 1
```

Output

```
285
```

MSSQL

```
select top 1 question_id as survey_log
from
(
    SELECT sum(CASE WHEN action='answer' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num,
    question_id,
    count(distinct id) as den
    from
    survey_log
    group by question_id
) b
order by (num/den) desc
```

Output

```
369
```

For most of the scenarios, I used top 1 and limit 1 for similar results until this question. Somehow in this query, I get different results. Where am I going wrong? Is the order of execution different in MSSQL for `TOP` clause? Or I'm totally confusing the use-case of the two?

Original Question from [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/get-highest-answer-rate-question/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, the division of two integers is an integer.  So, 1/2 = 0, not 0.5.

To fix this, use:

```
order by num * 1.0 / den
```

In addition, if there are duplicate values for the `order by` key, then an arbitrary equivalent row will be returned.